# WKWebview Timeout

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to configure the timeout on a `WKWebView`. Using `URLRequest` it is possible to set it for the initial request, but any website internal requests (e.g. following a link) seem to have their own request.

Is there a way to configure the timeout for all website internal requests?